# No value given for one or more required parameters error - Excel

Tags: c#, .net, excel, winforms, datagridview

I am getting data from excel and showing it in DataGridWiew.
I have two textboxes, one is for starting index for first record and other is for last record.

Code works fine. But lets suppose starting record is 1 and ending is 10 when I change 10 to 1 or 2 it gives me an error in this line:

**adapter.Fill(dataTable);**

Full Code is below:

```
public DataSet Parse(string fileName)
{
    string connectionString = string.Format("provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; data source = {0}; Extended Properties = Excel 8.0;", fileName);

    DataSet data = new DataSet();

    foreach (var sheetName in GetExcelSheetNames(connectionString))
    {
        using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
        {
            string query = "";
            var dataTable = new DataTable();
            if(tbStarting.Text.Trim()=="" && tbEnding.Text.Trim() == "")
            {
                query = string.Format("SELECT * FROM [{0}]", sheetName);
            }
            else
            {
                query = string.Format("SELECT * FROM [{0}] where SrNo between " + int.Parse(tbStarting.Text.Trim()) + " and " + int.Parse(tbEnding.Text.Trim()) + " order by SrNo", sheetName);
            }
            con.Open();
            OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, con);

            adapter.Fill(dataTable);
            data.Tables.Add(dataTable);
            con.Close();
        }
    }
    return data;
}
static string[] GetExcelSheetNames(string connectionString)
{
    OleDbConnection con = null;
    DataTable dt = null;
    con = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
    con.Open();
    dt = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);

    if (dt == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    String[] excelSheetNames = new String[dt.Rows.Count];
    int i = 0;

    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        excelSheetNames[i] = row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
        i++;
    }

    return excelSheetNames;
}
```

Why this is happening please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code, it seems that your procedure is working when you ask to retrieve all the record in **each table**. But you are not showing which table (Sheet) is actually used afterwars.

Chances are, you are using the first one only.

When you submit some parameters, only one of the tables (Sheets) can fulfill those requirements. The other(s) don't, possibly because a field named `[SrNo]` is not present.
This causes the *More Parameters Required* error when trying to apply a filter.

Not related to the error, but worth noting: you don't need to recreate the whole DataSet + DataTables to filter your DataSources.

`The DataSet.Tables[N].DefaultView.RowFilter` can be used to get the same result without destroying all the objects each time a filter is required.
RowFilter has some limitations in the language (e.g. does not support `BETWEEN`, `Field >= Value1 AND Field <= Value2` must be used), but it's quite effective.

This is a possible setup:
(`xDataSet` is a placeholder for your actual `DataSet`)

```
//Collect the values in the TextBoxes in a string array
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] Ranges = new string[] { tbStarting.Text.Trim(), tbEnding.Text.Trim() };

    if (xDataSet != null)
        FilterDataset(Ranges);
}


private void FilterDataset(string[] Ranges)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Ranges[0]) & string.IsNullOrEmpty(Ranges[1]))
        xDataSet.Tables[0].DefaultView.RowFilter = null;
    else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Ranges[0]) | string.IsNullOrEmpty(Ranges[1]))
        return;
    else if (int.Parse(Ranges[0]) < int.Parse(Ranges[1]))
        xDataSet.Tables[0].DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("SrNo >= {0} AND SrNo <= {1}", Ranges[0], Ranges[1]);
    else
        xDataSet.Tables[0].DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("SrNo = {0}", Ranges[0]);

    this.dataGridView1.Update();
}
```

I've modified your code you code a bit to handle those requirements.
(I've left here those filters anyway; they're not used, but if you still want  them, they are in a working condition)

```
DataSet xDataSet = new DataSet();
string WorkBookPath = @"[Excel WorkBook Path]";
//Query one Sheet only. More can be added if necessary
string[] WBSheetsNames = new string[] { "Sheet1" };

//Open the Excel document and assign the DataSource to a dataGridView
xDataSet = Parse(WorkBookPath, WBSheetsNames, null);
dataGridView1.DataSource = xDataSet.Tables[0];
dataGridView1.Refresh();


public DataSet Parse(string fileName, string[] WorkSheets, string[] ranges)
{
    if (!File.Exists(fileName)) return null;
    string connectionString = string.Format("provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; " + 
                                            "data source = {0}; " + 
                                            "Extended Properties = \"Excel 12.0;HDR=YES\"", 
                                             fileName);
    DataSet data = new DataSet();
    string query = string.Empty;

    foreach (string sheetName in GetExcelSheetNames(connectionString))
    {
        foreach (string WorkSheet in WorkSheets)
            if (sheetName == (WorkSheet + "$"))
            {
                using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
                    if ((ranges == null) || 
                        (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ranges[0]) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(ranges[1])) ||
                        (int.Parse(ranges[0]) > int.Parse(ranges[1]))) 
                        query = string.Format("SELECT * FROM [{0}]", sheetName);

                    else if ((int.Parse(ranges[0]) == int.Parse(ranges[1])))
                        query = string.Format("SELECT * FROM [{0}] WHERE SrNo = {1}", sheetName, ranges[0]);
                    else
                        query = string.Format("SELECT * FROM [{0}] WHERE (SrNo BETWEEN {1} AND {2}) " +
                                              "ORDER BY SrNo", sheetName, ranges[0], ranges[1]);
                    con.Open();
                    OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, con);

                    adapter.Fill(dataTable);
                    data.Tables.Add(dataTable);
                };
            }
    }
    return data;
}

static string[] GetExcelSheetNames(string connectionString)
{
    string[] excelSheetNames = null;
    using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
    {
        con.Open();
        using (DataTable dt = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null))
        {
            if (dt != null)
            {
                excelSheetNames = new string[dt.Rows.Count];
                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    excelSheetNames[i] = dt.Rows[i]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return excelSheetNames;
}
```